# Group dataframe and sample n rows with equal probability between groups

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, probability, sample

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
     ID  Value
0     a     2
1     a     4
2     b     6
3     c     8
4     c    10
5     c    12
```

I would like to sample equally from the `ID` groups. I know I can group the data frame by ID and then specify the number of rows I want to sample from each group like this:
`df.groupby("ID").sample(n=2, replace = True)`
However, I just want the probability of sampling from a group to be the same, not necessarily the exact same number of rows.

Comment: But is this an issue to have the same number of rows? This methods seems to be the most straightforward

Comment: Why not just define n as whatever percentage of the samples it is that you want instead of it being a static 2?

Comment: can you post your desired output as table?

Comment: Simply random sampling will, of course, result in a sample with the same probability as the groups exist. Do you want to fix the number of sampled rows for each group?

Comment: @PandaKim I think they want the same as they currently have but not necessarily an exact identical number per group, just on average.

Comment: @mozway Lets say I want to sample 5 rows in total, then I cannot specify how many rows per group, as this does not add up.. So I would have to round up or down, but then I would not get the specific number of rows that I want.

Comment: You will always have the rounding problem. pandas.sample appears to round up and show duplicates for n=2 when you only have one sample as you have with ID='b'.

Comment: @Jamie Yes.. I was hoping there was some way of grouping and then maybe specifying a probability for each group (which in my case would be the same for all groups) and then sample n rows in total from the full dataframe, if that makes sense?

Comment: @mnoerregaard You can just filter the df for each of the unique ID's in a loop, define your probability function for each group and then add the elements for each column to a list and then add those lists to your new df that contains only the records that you want based on your probability function.  I am not sure what you mean by the 'probability for each group,' but that is the basic answer.  I am not aware of a pre-made functionthat will do this.

Comment: @mnoerregaard got it, see below for an approach to get exactly N rows with equal probabilities per group

Comment: @Jamie Its a laarge df, so I would really like to avoid looping as much as possible. But yes, that is definately a solution, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sample `N` rows with about the same probability to sample each group, you could oversample per group then sample again:

```
import math

N = 4

out = (df.groupby('ID').sample(n=math.ceil(N/df['ID'].nunique()), replace=True)
         .sample(N)
      )
```

Example output:

```
  ID  Value
2  b      6
2  b      6
4  c     10
1  a      4
```

With `N = 10`:

```
  ID  Value
0  a      2
2  b      6
5  c     12
3  c      8
1  a      4
5  c     12
2  b      6
1  a      4
1  a      4
2  b      6
```

Proportion with `N = 100`:

```
ID
b    0.34
a    0.33
c    0.33
Name: proportion, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using frac instead of n in your sample code. To use 50% of the samples for a given ID:

```
newdf=df.groupby("ID").sample(frac=0.5, replace = True)
display(newdf)
```

Comment: If "frac" mean 50% from each group, then I will still not be able to specify the total number of rows that I want, I think, which I would like to be able to.

Comment: @mnoerregaard Then it is not clear what you mean when you say 'I just want the probability of sampling from a group to be the same, not necessarily the exact same number of rows.'  Can you explain?

Comment: Yes, I will try: So lets say I want 10 rows in total from my dataframe, but instead of equal probability of sampling a row (df.sample(n=10)) , I want equal probability of sampling a row with a specific ID.